# yii2 deployment in rackspace cloud site

Tags: php, web-deployment, yii2, rackspace-cloud

I am trying to deploy a yii2 website in rackspace cloud site for testing and I get this error and the site main page never shows up

[11-Jun-2014 14:10:07 America/Chicago] exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/yaz.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/yaz.so: undefined symbol: pval_destructor' in Unknown:0
Stack trace:

## 0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()

## 1 {main}

Yii2 web site works perfectly on my MAC localhost but not on the server. I verified that all requrirements are passed in the server(I could access requirements.php through url on server and it passed). The server has PHP 5.4.10.

Any thoughts?